# How to "cut off" table diagonally from typesetting empty cells

Tags: tables

So, I have next table:
[image]

How I could typeset that in tabular? I mean, the table is cut across red line diagonally because there will be empty cells all around right down corner.

Comment: Have a look at page 11 of the `nicematrix` documentation

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Just checked it out. Exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\[
\newcommand{\?}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{wc{1em}|}{#1}}
\begin{array}{|>{\vphantom{\Big|}}w{c}{1em}|*{8}{w{c}{1em}}}
\hline
  & \?{x^6} & \?{x^5} & \?{x^4} & \?{x^3} & \?{x^2} & \?{x^1} & \?{x^0} & \?{} \\
\hline
x & \?{3}   & \?{-4}  & \?{-4}  & \?{2}   & \?{-3}  & \?{2}   & \?{-3}  & \?{A_i} \\
\hline
2 & \?{3}   & \?{1}   & \?{2}   & \?{10}  & \?{13}  & \?{16}  & \?{19}  & \?{A_0} \\
\cline{1-9}
2 & \?{3}   & \?{10}  & \?{11}  & \?{12}  & \?{0}   & \?{-2}  & \?{A_1} \\
\cline{1-8}
2 & \?{3}   & \?{4}   & \?{8}   & \?{10}  & \?{6}   & \?{A_2} \\
\cline{1-7}
2 & \?{3}   & \?{5}   & \?{3}   & \?{2}   & \?{A_3} \\
\cline{1-6}
2 & \?{3}   & \?{0}   & \?{1}   & \?{A_4} \\
\cline{1-5}
2 & \?{3} & \?{2} & \?{A_5} \\
\cline{1-4}
2 & \?{3} & \?{A_6} \\
\cline{1-3}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not bad. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{NiceMatrix}[hvlines,corners=SE,columns-width=auto]
  & x^6 & x^5 & x^4 & x^3 & x^2 & x^1 & x^0 &  \\
x & 3   & -4  & -4  & 2   & -3  & 2   & -3  & A_i \\
2 & 3   & 1   & 2   & 10  & 13  & 16  & 19  & A_0 \\
2 & 3   & 10  & 11  & 12  & 0   & -2  & A_1 \\
2 & 3   & 4   & 8   & 10  & 6   & A_2 \\
2 & 3   & 5   & 3   & 2   & A_3 \\
2 & 3   & 0   & 1   & A_4 \\
2 & 3 & 2 & A_5 \\
2 & 3 & A_6 \\
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

The key `corners=SE` means that the corner of the empty cells in the corner SE (= *south east*) will be computed. The lines (required by the key `hvlines`) won't be drawn in that corner.

[image: Output of the above code]